# CKEditor can't change input elements - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I have spent a long time trying to identify why I could not change input elements from CKEditor. What is the solution?

Comment: We like self-answered questions (and there's no need to justify that in the question itself), but please do stick to the Q&A format. Ask the question that you then answer, don't skimp on details or presuppose anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deal was to remove "tabindex" attribute from the modals. That did the trick!